# Terraform does not detect manual removal of Operations and Definitions in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am managing **Azure APIM API** using Terraform. When my underlying App Service changes, I update the respective APIM API definition using the Swagger URL of the App Service.

This is my TF Code:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "apimapi" {
  api_management_name   = var.api_management_name
  api_type              = "http"
  description           = null
  display_name          = var.display_name
  name                  = lower(var.display_name)
  path                  = lower(var.display_name)
  protocols             = ["https"]
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  revision              = "1"
  revision_description  = null
  service_url           = var.service_url
  source_api_id         = null
  subscription_required = true
  terms_of_service_url  = null
  version               = null
  version_description   = null
  version_set_id        = null
  subscription_key_parameter_names {
    header = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"
    query  = "subscription-key"
  }
  import {
    content_format = "openapi+json"
    content_value  = data.http.contracts.response_body
  }
}

data "http" "contracts" {
  url = "${var.service_url}swagger/v1/swagger.json"
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}
```

Issue is, when/if I manually remove any Operations or Definitions from the same API and run my Terraform code again, ideally it should detect the change and perform an update in place for the deleted operations and definitions.
However, I get **No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.** on running terraform plan.

This is weird because if I change any other property manually, let's say the **service_url** on Azure Portal and then run terraform plan, it detects that manual change against the state file and suggests an update in place for the same.

So why it does not detect the change/removal of API operations and/or definitions from the API?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal, this is how terraform is working.

Terraform used 2 files:
1- TF configuration file (contains the desired state of your resources)
2- TF state file (store the actual state of your resources, as stated in the TF config file)

When you use Terraform to create or update resources, the current resource configuration is saved in the state file.

Terraform assumes that the state file always matches the actual resource configuration. and compares any probable changes with the state file.

So, if you make any changes manually (out of terraform), it doesn't change the state file. so for terraform, he will never know that there is changes happened to the resources.

Hope that clarify your issue!

Comment: I understand that but my situation is:
When I manually update a property let's say "service_url" on Azure Portal and then when I run Terraform plan, it detects that the actual value of service_url is different from the one in the state and shows an update-in-place will take place as part of the plan.

But when I delete any Operations or definitions in the API manually on portal, which corresponds to the "import" block in above code, it does not detect that change and says no changes required, infra matches the configuration.